# How to preserve string data when using df.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a dataframe that looks like this with a ticker column like this:

```
date
2018-03-30    0001
2018-03-29    0001
2018-03-28    0001
```

It takes about 10 mins to run so once finished I use the df.to_csv to create a file for quick load.   My problem is when I df.to_csv('df.csv')  then read the csv back in, the ticker values changes to 1 rather than 0001.

```
date
2018-03-30       1
2018-03-29       1
2018-03-28       1
2018-03-27       1
```

How can I preserve the original format (0001 not 1) on the df.to_csv ?

Comment: Can you right click and open as txt , then I think the lead zero is there

Comment: @Wen yes you are right-  the csv file does contain 0001-  any clues on how to how to get the 0001 in the from_csv dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you reading from csv

```
yourdf=pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv', dtype=object)
```

Comment: @TimothyLombardbase on the file *Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.* https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html