# Preserve string when writing pandas data frame to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column of strings (yes, they are the same in this example):

```
                col_name
0      86465872771915826
1      86465872771915826
2      86465872771915826
3      86465872771915826
4      86465872771915826
```

All of those are strings in this data frame ( I checked with `type()` function on each element. But when I do `df.to_csv('out.csv')`, those strings are automatically converted into scientific float like following:

```
8.6459E+16
8.6459E+16
8.6459E+16
8.6459E+16
8.6459E+16
```

where, if I expand those numbers in Excel, I would see the last two digits (i.e. `26`) being exchanged with zeroes:

```
86465872771915800
```

How to write csv preserving the strings as they are in the data frame?

***More details***: could someone reopen my question? I see the suggestion of duplication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593828/how-to-preserve-string-data-when-using-df-to-csv). But it is not the same. My string data frame are created in other operation form JSON elsewhere, not read from a csv source.

Comment: Could you explain more? The only solution in that thread is asking to read back to csv? ```Since you reading from csv

yourdf=pd.read_csv('yourcsv.csv', dtype=object)```. How does preserve the writing from df to csv?

Comment: changed dupe, can you check?

Comment: @TristanTran, can you try opening the file in a text editor and check. The issue may not be with the csv file but with the editor itself. The value may be saved correctly but the editor may change the display format especially when you open it in a spreadsheet editor.

Comment: @heretolearn Thanks. Just did. You are right. Excel seems to do something to the large number. I open in Notepad and the string is completely preserved. Also, thanks to jezrael for the link.